# Escape curly brace '{' in String.Format

Tags: c#, .net, string

How do I display a literal curly brace character when using the String.Format method?

Example:

```
sb.AppendLine(String.Format("public {0} {1} { get; private set; }", 
prop.Type, prop.Name));
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
public Int32 MyProperty { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 1600, accepted):

Use double braces `{{` or `}}` so your code becomes:

```
sb.AppendLine(String.Format("public {0} {1} {{ get; private set; }}", 
prop.Type, prop.Name));

// For prop.Type of "Foo" and prop.Name of "Bar", the result would be:
// public Foo Bar { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Straight from the documentation: <quote>To specify a single literal brace character in format, specify two leading or trailing brace characters; that is, "{{" or "}}".</quote>  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx

Comment: Oddly enough, Microsoft removed the {{ notation from MSDN since version 4.5.

Comment: @Olivier I still get a `FormatException` when targeting .NET 4.5 with `{}` in the string; `{{}}` works.

Comment: For those wondering, the documentation wasn't removed, just moved. It's now at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx

Comment: **Related:** When using `Console.WriteLine(string)`, the curly braces do not need escapes.  However, when using `Console.WriteLine(string, params object[])`, escapes are required.

I've not tested how this applies for `String.Format` for when no additional arguments are added.

Comment: works with string literal in new c# as well `$"this will {{{something}}} to look like JSON"`

Comment: This answer is only good if the string is a string literal you write. What if it is a string variable from another source? How can I escape the  {} in a string variable like "hello {world}" to pass in to another method that wrongly tries to use it as a formatter? Do I use regular expression to replace {}?