# how to ignore { character?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to ignore { character in string is it possible ?

thanks for help

```
String.Format("function(s, e) {  {0}.PerformCallback(MyObject.GetSelectedItem().value); }", getClientName);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape curly brace '{' in String.Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773857/escape-curly-brace-in-string-format) - to all you "helpful" answerers: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2011/01/05.html :)

Comment: @bzlm, I'll see your Joel, and raise you a [Jeff](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to double the curly braces in order to escape them:

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, @"
    function(s, e) {{
        {0}.PerformCallback(MyObject.GetSelectedItem().value);
    }}", getClientName);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the curly brace by typing `{{` and it will display as one.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your single '{' with a double '{{'.

Answer (score 2):

The term you're after is 'delimit'. By replacing { with {{ and } with }} like so:

```
string.Format("function(s, e) {{  {0}.PerformCallback(MyObject.GetSelectedItem().value); }}", getClientName);
```

Answer (score 2):

> To specify a single literal brace character in format, specify two leading or trailing brace characters; that is, "{{" or "}}".

[Source: String.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you by ignore, mean that you want to get rid of it, you can use the following code:

```
myString = myString.Replace("{","");
```

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes use

```
char curly = '{';
String.Format("function(s, e), {0} {1}.PerformCallback(...)", curly, getClientName);
```

That way the format string is more readable.