# C# String.Format with Curly Bracket in string

Tags: c#, string-formatting, curly-braces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Escape curly brace '{' in String.Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773857/escape-curly-brace-in-string-format)

c# has a String.Format method that allows you to format a string but inserting params with the tokens `{0}` `{1}`

I am trying to create a simple json string which requires curly brackets to be in the string, and so it is breaking the formatter

```
String.Format("{ foo:'{0}', bar:'{1}' }", foo, bar);
```

Adding an escape before the braces did not help

Throws a exception saying my string is incorrectly formatted, anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: In Framework 4.6 or higher, you can do this ... 
 string moe = "Moe"; 
 string larry = "Larry";
 string curly = "{Curly}";
 string results = $"1:{moe} 2:{larry} 3:{curly}";

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can escape the braces by doubling them up in your format strings:

```
string.Format("{{ foo: '{0}', bar: '{1}' }}", foo, bar);
```

Answer (score 14):

You can simply use `{{` or `}}` to escape a curly brace.

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {{{2}}}", "Moe", "Larry", "Curly"));
```

produces:

Moe, Larry, {Curly}

Comment: You need to be careful about tripling-up on braces... in this case it works, but in general, does the parser view that as '{ {{' or '}} }'.  It can be better to create a {3} that is the brace itself