# String interpolation issues

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, string-interpolation

I'm trying to figure out why my unit test fails (The third assert below):

```
var date = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);

var formatted = "{countdown|" + date.ToString("o") + "}";

//Works
Assert.AreEqual(date.ToString("o"), $"{date:o}");
//Works
Assert.AreEqual(formatted, $"{{countdown|{date.ToString("o")}}}");
//This one fails
Assert.AreEqual(formatted, $"{{countdown|{date:o}}}");
```

AFAIK, this should work correctly, but it appears that it doesn't pass the formatting parameter in correctly, it it appears as just `{countdown|o}` to the code. Any idea why this is failing?

Comment: It appears (though I hate saying it) that it's a compiler bug.

Comment: @DavidG: Could be a compiler bug, or could be a bug in the underlying formatting library, but I agree that something smells bad here. It at least should be investigated.

Comment: It seems to be to do with the way the closing interpolation bracket is evaulated. With the code above the outer bracket closes the interpolation `{{countdown|**{**date:o}}**}**`, a space between the brackets causes it to evaluate to the inner bracket `{{countdown|**{**date:o**}**_}}`.

Comment: Note the issue is not due to string interpolation, it's inside `string.Format` somewhere (e.g. `string.Format("{{{0:o}}}", date)`)

Comment: I think you ment `Assert.AreEqual(formatted, $"{{{$"countdown|{date:o}"}}}");`

Comment: It looks like `o` is interpreted as a part of custom date time format. And since it isn't valid format specifier it's just copied to output. See (Custom Date and Time Format Strings documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#sSpecifier).

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev `o` is a standard format string though https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#Roundtrip

Comment: this should work `$"{{countdown|{date:o}"+"}";` it can not manage the closing curl and the double curl escape - it starts escaping from left to right

Comment: @DavidG That is correct, but it looks like it is interpreted as custom.

Comment: @FrankerZ Your bounty says this is a bug, but I don't think it is, it's just a symptom of how the braces are counted up and the answer from user1892538 demonstrates this perfectly.

Comment: My bounty says it *may* be a bug.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem with this line

```
Assert.AreEqual(formatted, $"{{countdown|{date:o}}}");
```

is that you have 3  curly quotes after the `format string` of the variable to be escaped and it starts escaping from left to right, therefore it treats the first 2  curly quotes as *part of the format string* and the third curly quote as the closing one.

So it transforms `o` in `o}` and the it's unable to interpolate it.

This should work

```
Assert.AreEqual(formatted, $"{{countdown|{date:o}"+"}");
```

Notice that the simpler `$"{date}}}"` (i.e. 3 curls after the variable *without* a `format string`) does work because it recognizes that the first curly quote is the closing one, while the interpretation of the format specifier after the `:` breaks the correct closing parenthesis identification.

**To prove that the format string is escaped** like a string, consider that the following

```
$"{date:\x6f}"
```

is treated as

```
$"{date:o}"
```

Finally, it is perfectly possible that the double escaped curly quotes are part of a custom date format, so it is absolutely reasonable the behaviour of the compiler. Again, a concrete example

```
$"{date:MMM}}dd}}yyy}" // it's a valid feb}09}2017
```

Parsing is a formal process based on expression grammar rules, can't be done by just glancing at it.

Comment: The number of braces is not an issue as `$"{{{date:o}}}"` still produces invalid output.

Comment: @DavidG *3 curly quotes* after the format string `o` *do* produce invalid output, as I have written in my answer - that is now **correct**

Comment: Nice analysis. I am surprised to learn that the lexer treats the `}}}` which follows the format specifier as an escaped `}` followed by a meaningful `}`. I would have naively expected the rule to be "once you find a meaningful `{`, parse formatted expressions until you find the matching `}`, and then resume the regular string lexing. Next time I see Neal I'll ask what led to this somewhat surprising result.

Comment: Another example is `Console.WriteLine(" {0} is rendered as  {0:000}}000.000}",2000.4);` where the output is  `2000,4 is rendered as  002}000,400` and so, once it finds a meaningful `{`, it parses untill it finds the matching `}` or a `:` and in the latter case it resume the `}` escaping

Comment: @user1892538 Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: @FrankerZ yep, but in either case... just let me quote this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114619/c-sharp-string-format-with-curly-bracket-in-string#comment8524941_7114654) of about 6 years ago...

Comment: @user1892538 Very nice observation. I am surprised why this is not accepted as answer yet..

Answer (score 6):

This is a *follow-up* to my original answer in order

> to make sure this is the intended behavior

As far as an official source is concerned, we should refer to the [Interpolated Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) from msdn.

The structure of an interpolated string is

```
$ " <text> { <interpolation-expression> <optional-comma-field-width> <optional-colon-format> } <text> ... } "
```

and each single interpolation is formally defined with a syntax

```
single-interpolation:  
    interpolation-start  
    interpolation-start : regular-string-literal  

interpolation-start:  
    expression  
    expression , expression
```

What counts here is that

1. the `optional-colon-format` is defined as a `regular-string-literal` syntax => i.e. it can contains an `escape-sequence`, according to the `paragraph 2.4.4.5 String literals` of the [C# Language Specification 5.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029)
2. You can use an interpolated string anywhere you can use a `string literal`
3. To include a curly brace (`{` or `}`) in an interpolated string use two curly braces, `{{` or `}}` => i.e. the compiler *escapes* two curly braces in the `optional-colon-format`
4. the compiler scans the contained interpolation `expressions` as balanced text until it finds a comma, colon, or close curly brace => i.e. a colon *breaks* the balanced text *as well as* a close curly brace

Just to be clear, this explains the difference between `$"{{{date}}}"` where `date` is an `expression` and so it is tokenized until the first curly brace versus `$"{{{date:o}}}"` where `date` is again an `expression` and now it is tokenized until the first colon, after which a *regular string literal* begins and the compiler resumes escaping two curly braces, etc...

There is also the [String Formatting FAQ](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brada/2004/01/14/string-formatting-faq/) from msdn, where this case was explicitly treated.

```
int i = 42;
string s = String.Format(“{{{0:N}}}”, i);   //prints ‘{N}’
```

> The question is, why did this last attempt fail? There’s two things
>   you need to know in order to understand this result:
>
> When providing a format specifier, string formatting takes these
>   steps:
>
> Determine if the specifier is longer than a single character: if so,
>   then assume that the specifier is a custom format. A custom format
>   will use suitable replacements for your format, but if it doesn’t know
>   what to do with some character, it will simply write it out as a
>   literal found in the format Determine if the single character
>   specifier is a supported specifier (such as ‘N’ for number
>   formatting). If it is, then format appropriately. If not, throw an
>   `ArgumnetException`
>
> When attempting to determine whether a curly bracket should be
>   escaped, the curly brackets are simply treated in the order they are
>   received. Therefore, `{{{` will escape the first two characters and
>   print the literal `{`, and the the third curly bracket will begin the
>   formatting section. On this basis, in `}}}` the first two curly
>   brackets will be escaped, therefore a literal `}` will be written to
>   the format string, and then the last curly bracket will be assumed to
>   be ending a formatting section With this information, we now can
>   figure out what’s occurring in our `{{{0:N}}}` situation. The first
>   two curly brackets are escaped, and then we have a formatting section.
>   However, we then also escape the closing curly bracket, before closing
>   the formatting section. Therefore, our formatting section is actually
>   interpreted as containing `0:N}`. Now, the formatter looks at the
>   format specifier and it sees `N}` for the specifier. It therefore
>   interprets this as a custom format, and since neither N or } mean
>   anything for a custom numeric format, these characters are simply
>   written out, rather than the value of the variable referenced.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed followup.

Answer (score 2):

Problem seems to be that to insert a parenthesis while using string interpolation you you need to escape it by duplicating it. If you add the parenthesis used for the interpolation itself, we end up with a triple parenthesis such as the one you have in the line that gives you the exception:

```
Assert.AreEqual(formatted, $"{{countdown|{date:o}}}");
```

Now, if we observe the "**}}}"**, we can notice that the first parenthesis encloses the string interpolation, while the final two are meant to be treated as a string-escaped parenthesis character.

The compiler however, is treating the first two as the scaped string character, thus it's inserting a string between the interpolation delimiters. Basically the compiler is doing something like this:

```
string str = "a string";
$"{str'}'}"; //this would obviously generate a compile error which is bypassed by this bug
```

You can resolve this by reformatting the line as such:

```
Assert.AreEqual(formatted, $"{{countdown|{$"{date:o}"}}}");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way to get the assert to work...

```
Assert.AreEqual(formatted, "{" + $"countdown|{date:o}" + "}");
```

In this form...

```
Assert.AreEqual(formatted, $"{{countdown|{date:o}}}");
```

The first 2 closing braces are interpreted as a literal closing brace and the third as closing the formatting expression.

This is not a bug so much as a limitation of the grammar for interpolated strings.  The bug, if there is one, is that the output of the formatted text should probably be "o}" instead of just "o".

The reason we have the operator "+=" instead of "=+" in C, C#, and C++ is that in the form =+ you cannot tell in some cases whether the "+" is part of the operator or a unary "+".