# InterpolatedString with three braces

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0, string-interpolation

I have an interpolated string which ends with an argument followed by a closing brace.
It needs to have a formatting argument, however the string is taking the first double brace as the escaped brace and remaining as the brace closing the argument:

```
> $"foo:{16:x}"
"foo:10"
> $"foo:{16:x}}}"
"foo:x}"
```

How to I correctly write the interpolated string so that I get `foo:10}`?

Comment: Impressively, there's even a special error message if you try to escape the `}` as `\u007d`! Someone was really fond of their grammar.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42142003/1997232).

Comment: [Also related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40016188/how-to-use-string-format-to-format-a-hex-number-surrounded-by-curly-brackets)

Comment: You're right @JeroenMostert.  `Error CS8087: A '}' character may only be escaped by doubling '}}' in an interpolated string.`.  That just seems mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no direct syntax for that, unfortunately;

```
$"foo:{16:x}{'}'}" // or $"foo:{16:x}{"}"}"
```

is a hack that'll work; otherwise, perhaps simply concatenate

Comment: Personally, as far as hacks go, I'd prefer to leave the `}` out of it: `$"foo:{16:x}{null}}}"` or `$"foo:{16:x}{""}}}"` also work. But that's perhaps just a matter of opinion.

Comment: @hvd yeah, once you're down to choosing your *favorite* ugly hack, it is a poor choice

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  Interestingly, concatenation doesn't work as the result isn't a `FormattableString`.

Comment: @BanksySan you never specified that it *had to be* a `FormattableString` :) the compiler actively prefers *not* to do that - see `Foo($"test {val}");` with `Foo(string x)` and `Foo(FormattableString x)` to see what I mean

Comment: It doesn't have to be (my use case is that it is) but the problem exists whether it is there or not.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad do you mean the comment above? if so: "it chooses `Foo(string)`, not `Foo(FormattableString)`" - that do?