# When using brackets in String: "Input string was not in a correct format"

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, string-formatting

How can I format a String in C# where the pattern has brackets? When I run the following statement...

```
String.Format("Foo { Bar={0} }", this.Bar);
```

... I receive a runtime exception:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Should I have to escape the brackets? How to?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Escape the brackets by doubling the brackets like `{{` and `}}`

```
String.Format("Foo {{ Bar={0} }}", this.Bar);
```

Answer (score 4):

This situation is explained on MSDN in the article [Composite Formatting - Escaping Braces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)

> Opening and closing braces are interpreted as starting and ending a
>   format item. Consequently, you must use an escape sequence to display
>   a literal opening brace or closing brace. Specify two opening braces
>   ("{{") in the fixed text to display one opening brace ("{"), or two
>   closing braces ("}}") to display one closing brace ("}").

So this should be your solution

```
String.Format("Foo {{ Bar={0} }}", this.Bar);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using double curly braces, so it looks like:

```
String.Format("Foo {{ Bar={0} }}", this.Bar);
```

Looks like it has already been answered: [Escape curly brace '{' in String.Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773857/escape-curly-brace-in-string-format)