# String.Format returning an error

Tags: c#, string.format

This has me scratching my head.

I have a function that returns a string containing json-like data for an autocomplete control, but can't get `String.Format` to work:

```
private string GetUsers(string crit)
{
    string result = "";

    using (DataTable dt = dl.GetRecordSet("select ob_id, ob_desc from objects where ac_id = @acid and ob_desc like @crit and ot_id = 29 and ob_deleted = 0 order by ob_desc", new[] { MyApplicationSession.AccountId, "%" + crit + "%" }))
    {
        result = "[ ";
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            result += string.Format("{ \"id\": \"{0}\", \"label\": \"{1}\", \"value\": \"{1}\" },", dr["ob_id"].ToString(), dr["ob_desc"].ToString());
        }

        result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1); // remove trailing comma
        result += "]";
    }
    return result;
}
```

I always receive the error "`Input string was not in a correct format.`".

`dr["ob_id"].ToString()` is an integer and `dr["ob_desc"].ToString()` is a varchar in the SQL Server 2008 database.

Visual Studio also advises under Troubleshooting Tips that "When converting a string to DateTime...", no idea where it gets that from.

I have tried variations such as replacing \" with ', replacing \" with "" and explicitly casting the parameters as (string).

The only thing I find to work is putting the values directly in the string and omitting string.Format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got some extra curly-brackets in there, which confuses the parser.  Escape them like `{{`:

```
string.Format("{{ \"id\": \"{0}\", \"label\": \"{1}\", \"value\": \"{1}\" }},", ...
```

([Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3773857/1001985))

Comment: Blindingly obvious in hindsight... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have encased your entire string in `{...}`, in `String.Format`, to output an actual curly brace, you need to do `{{` and `}}` like so:

```
result += string.Format("{{ \"id\": \"{0}\", \"label\": \"{1}\", \"value\": \"{1}\" }},", dr["ob_id"].ToString(), dr["ob_desc"].ToString());
```