# string contains {} and templated

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am using httpwebrequest to communicate with a restful service and I need to send a json.
I want the json format to be configurable therefore I am trying to use a string template and format:

```
string template ="{ \"content\" : \"{0}\" }";
string.format(template,"my data");
```

But I get an exception of bad format.
Any ideas on how to.create a template containing curly brackets?

Thanks ahead,
Alon

Comment: Read it. Already available http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773857/escape-curly-brace-in-string-format

Answer (score 3):

You have to *escape* brackets as explained [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-brackets-curly-braces-in-a-format-string-in-net) and on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string template ="{{ \"content\" : \"{0}\" }}";
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
string template ="{{ \"content\" : \"{0}\" }}";
string.Format(template,"my data");
```

You need to escape the braces that are not used to specify a parameter.