# "Input string was not in a correct format" error

Tags: c#

The following Script shows the

> "index was outside the bounds of the array"

at line

```
for (int i = 0; i <u_f.GetLength(1); i++)
```

when I change it to

```
for (int i = 0; i <=u_f.GetLength(1); i++)
```

it shows

> "Input string was not in a correct format"

error in line `int uid = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_id.Text);`

```
        float userscore,itemscore,result;
        string lineitem, lineuser;
        //float[][] a = new float[89395][100];
        //float[][] b = new float[1143600][100];
        float[][] a = Enumerable.Range(0, 89395).Select(i => new float[100]).ToArray();
        float[][] b = Enumerable.Range(0, 1143600).Select(j => new float[100]).ToArray();
        //float[,] c = new float[89395, 100];
        StreamReader fileitem = new StreamReader("c:\\1.txt");
        StreamReader fileuser = new StreamReader("c:\\2.txt");
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int x = 0; x <= 8939500; x++)
        {
            lineuser = fileuser.ReadLine();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lineuser))
            {
                string[] values = lineuser.Split(' ');
                int userid, factoriduser;
                foreach (string value in values)
                {
                    userid = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
                    factoriduser = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
                    userscore = Convert.ToSingle(values[2]);
                    a[userid][factoriduser] = userscore;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int y = 0; y <= 114360000; y++)
        {
            lineitem = fileitem.ReadLine();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lineitem))
            {
                string[] valuesi = lineitem.Split(' ');
                int itemid, factoriditem;
                foreach (string value in valuesi)
                {
                    itemid = Convert.ToInt32(valuesi[0]);
                    factoriditem = Convert.ToInt32(valuesi[1]);
                    itemscore = Convert.ToSingle(valuesi[2]);
                    b[itemid][factoriditem] = itemscore;
                }
            }

        }

    }
    public float dotproduct(int userid,int itemid)
    {

        //get the score of 100 from user and item to dotproduct
        float[] u_f = a[userid];
        float[] i_f = b[itemid];

        for (int i = 0; i <u_f.GetLength(1); i++)  //<----error
        {
            result += u_f[userid] * i_f[itemid];
        }
        return result;

    }

    private void btn_recomm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(txtbx_id.Text==null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please insert user id");
        }
     if (txtbx_id.Text != null && txtbx_itemid==null)
      {
       int sc = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_id.Text);
       if (sc>=0 &&sc<=89395)
        {
          for (int z=0;z<=1143600;z++)
            {
              dotproduct(sc,z);
            }
          Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
           //put the result in hashtable
             foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in hashtable)
               {
                 System.Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
               }
        }
     }
        if (txtbx_id!=null && txtbx_itemid!=null)
        {
            int uid = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_id.Text);     //<----error
            int iid = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_itemid.Text); 
            {
                if (uid>=0 && uid<=89395 && iid>=0 && iid<=1143600)
                {
                    dotproduct(uid,iid);
                    MessageBox.Show("The Score of user id "+uid+" is "+result);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the value of `txtbx_id.Text`?

Comment: You have a 1D array, so `.GetLength(1)` is out-of-bounds because your array only has one dimension (the argument to `GetLength` is zero-based). Use `.GetLength(0)` or better yet, just `.Length`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "index was outside the bounds of the array"

**Problem 1:** You are accessing the `GetLength(1)` elements from invalid dimension.
you have only 1 dimension array but accessing second dimension Length as always Array Index starts from zero.

**Solution 1:** You should use `GetLength(0)` or `Length` as your array is single dimensional array.

`Array.GetLength(0)` returns the number of elements in the first dimension of the Array.

From MSDN:

> Gets a 32-bit integer that represents the number of elements in the
>   specified dimension of the Array.

Replace This:

```
for (int i = 0; i <u_f.GetLength(1); i++)
```

With This:

```
for (int i = 0; i <u_f.GetLength(0); i++)
```

OR With

```
  for (int i = 0; i <u_f.Length; i++)
```

**Problem 2:** you are doing `null` check for `TextBox` control directly but not for `TextBox` `Text/Value`. so what happens here is even if user does not enter any value in your textbox the if condition willnot fail as `TextBox` is not null.so it enters the if block but when it tries to convert that empty string/value into integer using following statement :

```
int uid = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_id.Text);     //<----error
```

as you said it throws exception.

**Solution 2:** You need to perform `null` check for `TextBox` value like `TextBox1.Text!=null`

**Suggestion 1:** You can use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` method to verify wether value is Null,Empty or WhiteSpace.

**Suggestion 2:** if you want to avoid runtime exceptions while parsing the user input into integer, you need to use `int.TryParse()` method.

Replace This:

```
if (txtbx_id!=null && txtbx_itemid!=null)
    {
        int uid = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_id.Text);     //<----error
        int iid = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_itemid.Text); 
        {
            if (uid>=0 && uid<=89395 && iid>=0 && iid<=1143600)
            {
                dotproduct(uid,iid);
                MessageBox.Show("The Score of user id "+uid+" is "+result);
            }
        }
    }
```

With This:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtbx_id.Text) &&      
     !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtbx_itemid.Text)) 
{
  int uid,iid;     
  if(int.TryParse(txtbx_id.Text,out uid) && int.TryParse(txtbx_itemid.Text,out iid))      
  {
    if (uid>=0 && uid<=89395 && iid>=0 && iid<=1143600)
    {
      dotproduct(uid,iid);
      MessageBox.Show("The Score of user id "+uid+" is "+result);
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: @user3328039: You are welcome , Glad tobe help of you.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi: Thorough explanation! +1

Comment: I would also either `TryParse` or else wrap in a try / catch block the part where you are converting a (user inputted) string to an integer. Never trust the user to actually type a number and not something else! Or even better - use a NumericUpDown control instead of a textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the problem:

```
int uid = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_id.Text);     //<----error
```

Try to use `Int32.TryParse` when having use input that can be different then expected:

```
int uid;
if (!Int32.TryParse(txtbx_id.Text, out uid))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Input is not a number! Try again!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Patrik Hofman. I don't need to use "if" here. I only wants to put the entry into the integer variable. How should I do that?

Comment: `Int32.TryParse` tries to parse the text to an `int`. If it fails, `Int32.TryParse` returns `false`. If it succeeds, it returns `true` and sets the value of `uid`.

Comment: @user3328039: The `if` is just to show a message in case of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your two errors are unrelated.  THe reason you're getting an error on

```
for (int i = 0; i < u_f.GetLength(1); i++)
```

is because u_f one has *one dimension*, but you are asking for the length of the *second* dimnsion (`GetLength` takes a 0-based dimension index).

Just use

```
for (int i = 0; i < u_f.Length; i++)
```

Your other error is caused by `txtbx_id.Text` not representing a valid `int` value.

In addition, this method is *guaranteed* to fail, because an array of length `x` does not have a value at `array[x]` (`array[x-1]` is the last item in the array):

```
public float dotproduct(int userid,int itemid)
{
    //get the score of 100 from user and item to dotproduct
    float[] u_f = a[userid];
    float[] i_f = b[itemid];

    for (int i = 0; i <u_f.GetLength(1); i++)  
    {
        result += u_f[userid] * i_f[itemid];  // this is GUARANTEED to fail 
    }
    return result;
}
```

I think you want

```
    for (int i = 0; i <u_f.Length; i++)  
    {
        result += u_f[i] * i_f[i];  
    }
```

instead.

Comment: @D Stanley, you mean I must define an array after "result += u_f[userid] * i_f[itemid];" line like: for (int i=0;i<u_f.length:i++)  { result+=u_f[userid]*i_f[itemid];  float [] arr= new [1143600];  float[i]=result;   }

Comment: @user3328039 Edited my answer to make a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this error when I had a ***single curly brace*** in a string (and the exception wasn't very helpful in figuring it out):

```
string result = string.Format("{label: '{0}, {1}', children: [", prefixLabel, prefixPointer);
```

---------------------------------------------------^-----------------------------

The solution in this case is doubled curly braces: `{{`  EG:

```
string result = string.Format("{{label: '{0}, {1}', children: [", prefixLabel, prefixPointer);
```

---------------------------------------------------^-----------------------------

I discovered that if I removed the curly brace just before the word label, the problem went away, so I Googled how to escape it.  Here's the link to the [***original SO Question***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773857/escape-curly-brace-in-string-format) I found on escaping curly braces, and it has many more links if you need more reading.

Hopefully this helps someone else who's confused by the “Input string was not in a correct format” error when they had no integers in their string similar to my experience just now.