# How to escape curly braces in Json string in C# string formatter

Tags: c#, json, string, formatting

I have problem in formatting json string in c#

I have following two lines

```
string formater = @"{'attachments':[{'title':'New item added','title_link':{0},'text':{1},'image_url':{2},'color':'#764FA5'}]}";
string myJson = String.Format(formater, product.Url, "text", product.ImageUrl);
```

I'm getting this Exception

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

I think because of curly braces inside formatting string, how can i escape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double curly braces
[Escape curly brace '{' in String.Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773857/escape-curly-brace-in-string-format)

Oh, and you will need to add quotes around you placeholders:

```
string formater = @"{{'attachments':[{{'title':'New item added','title_link':'{0}','text':'{1}','image_url':'{2}','color':'#764FA5'}}]}}";
string myJson = String.Format(formater, product.Url, "text", product.ImageUrl);
```