# Interpolation in the middle of a string

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I want to interpolation in the middle of a string, but I cannot use `String.Format`, because the string contains `{}` curly brackets.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
string code = "(function(){var myvariable = $"{variableToBeInterpolated}"});"
```

> Returns: ) expected ; expected

**Edit:** I tried the following snippet, the interpolation is now working, but the code is not executed in the browser.

```
"(function(){var myvariable=" + $"{myvariable c#}" + ")});"
```

Comment: Why does the string having `{` or `}` in it mean you can't use `string.Format`? Just [escape those characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-braces-curly-brackets-in-a-format-string-in-net).

Comment: You can use `String.Format` - just double your brackets

Comment: When I use string format like this: string.Format ((function () {var myvariable = {0}}), myvariable); returns: contains invalid placeholder

Comment: Why are you building up JavaScript via a string in the first place? What's the use care here?

Comment: I using cefsharp, method evaluatescript to execute JavaScript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### General Information

With C# version 6, extensive [string interpolation capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) have been added to the language.

> String interpolation provides a more readable and convenient syntax to
> create formatted strings than a [string composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting) feature.

To solve your problem, please have a look at the [special characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#special-characters) section of the documentation, which reads the following:

> To include a brace, "{" or "}", in the text produced by an
> interpolated string, use two braces, "{{" or "}}".

---

### Example

```
var variable = 10;
var code = $"(function() {{ var myVariable = {variable} }});";
Console.WriteLine(code);
```

> Output: `(function() { var myVariable = 10 });`

Comment: If my string contains more brackets, this method work?

Comment: @Slinidy sure, you just have to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to interpolate in the middle, rather put `$` in front. And for `{` you need to use `{{`. (the same applies for `}`)

```
string code = $"(function(){{ var myvariable = {myvariable} }});";
```

Comment: The simbol $ has to be in the middle if it does not bug the string because of the brackets

Comment: This SO post explains escaping curly braces using string.format. (works with string interpolation with $)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773857/escape-curly-brace-in-string-format

Comment: @nickgowdy tnx for the link. I rollbacked my first answer, which is actually correct one but the point is that I was confused with the actual requerements as @Slinidy said he wants `$` in the middle...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
string someVariable = "test";

string code = $"(function()'{{var myvariable = ({someVariable} in c#)}});"
```

Using $ in C# is string interpolation. Added in C# 6

[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: Did you try compiling this?

Comment: @KennethK.Sorry, my bad. You have to do double {{ }} otherwise it's a compilation error. Check my updated answer. I can't guarantee it will work at runtime, you'll need to try it out.